# Testing higherlevel javascript events

Tags: javascript, integration-testing

I am looking for a testing library for javascript that will work for spec-testing user interaction such as drag and drop, hovers, double/single clicks and drawing on a canvas.  I have looked at a couple libraries including jspec and jasmine but both seem to be more based on unit testing.

If I overlooked the fact that either of the above libraries support such testing I would love an example.

**Edit**

---

So I did a lot of looking last night and really didn't come across anything.  I would like if possible to emulate user interaction on a higher level than something like jasmine which is capybara style in the sense that it just fakes interaction with the dom.

I would like a library that actually emulates a mouse down -> mouse move -> mouse up event chain.

Does such a magical creation exist?

**Post bounty edit**

---

So, I have continued to experiment with JS testing libraries and am really not happy with how they function around using the html5 canvas.  It seems that with the canvas you cannot test events in jasmine because jasmine will not initialize the canvas.

I don't like that you must use "html" fixtures rather than actually testing application code.  That seems backwards if you are trying to integrate js into your app.  For spec testing it makes sense but BDD testing of a web framework would mandate it actually use application views for testing.

Again does such a monster exist or is my head in the clouds?

Comment: Have you tried Selenium or Watr?

Comment: I have used Selenium but I do not know of a selenium library for js that is good I just have used to web drivers to drive other testing frameworks forward.  Watr I just tried to google and got nothing so a link would be nice. Ty

Comment: Sorry, I spelled it wrong.  http://watir.com/

Comment: both of those still suffer the same fall that I cannot test things like drawing a line on a canvas...

Comment: I don't know of any js libraries designed for emulating user interaction through a nice API. You have to do this manually through the DOM events or jQuery.

Comment: @Raynos How would you emulate a drag event with jquery?

Comment: @austinbv are we talking about drag and drop Files or dragging and dropping anything from outside the browser into the browser? If so that isnt possible in javascript in the browser

Comment: No I am talking about drag and drop DOM elements.  So something like a test that would emulate a drag and a drop into a specific div, then a test that would drop it outside that div.

Comment: @austinbv just out of curiosity I was wondering if you eventually found a solution aside from selenium or watir?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried [PhantomJS](http://www.phantomjs.org/) or [ZombieJS](http://zombie.labnotes.org/)? I've heard good things about Phantom in particular.

=============

Another suggestion: Selenium plug-ins/macros. www.seleniumwiki.com/selenium-rc/selenium-mousedownat-mousemoveat-and-mouseupat-example/ or glauche.de/2009/09/09/drag-drop-with-selenium/ .

Answer (score 2):

I've seen the only good solution to this problem: [DOH Robot](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/util/dohrobot.html). It runs java applet, which allows to emit actual javascript events and emulate real user behavior (including drag-and-drop testing).

DOH doesn't depend on dojo, so you can use it in any project. Unfortunately it is not widely used, although it is really cool testing framework.

Answer (score 0):

Emulating user behaviour in JavaScript would require you to create custom `Event Object`s, dispatching them on an `Element`, and modifying their properties the most important of which are however *read-only* in standards compliant browsers.

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Event
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Event/UIEvent/MouseEvent
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.dispatchEvent

In IE 5+ they seem to be modifiable but that obviously excludes cross-browser testing.

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms535863(v=vs.85).aspx

<strike>So, I don't think what you have in mind is possible.</strike>

---

**Edit**: Thinking about it (and looking into the documentation for the *Selenium* Firefox extension), obviously you would be able to write a JavaScript program which according to a given schedule would programmatically create custom `Event Object`s that simulate user behaviour.

However, I'm not sure whether this is what Selenium does or -- more importantly -- whether this is a reliable way to do it. Aso it essentially means `"faking interaction with the DOM"` which you have ruled out.

Btw, let me get this correctly: so you essentially want a JavaScript library for testing the JavaScript part of your application; but, you also want it to work on the browser level (not on the level of the DOM engine), i.e. to simulate a genuine user interaction as if it was captured by the browser?

Comment: You don't modify properties on event objects. You're supposed to initialize them with the values for the properties when you first initialize the event itself. e.g. e=document.createEvent("UIEvent");e.initMouseEvent(...). Furthermore, events work on any Node or AbstractView (e.g. document, window), not just Elements.

Comment: @Eli Grey: That is what I'm saying here. You don't modify them. You would however have to, when attempting what the OP wants to do. Your second seems a little unprecise: you cannot register an `Event` on anything else then an `Element` (or -- with exceptions -- the `AbstractView`) nor can you dispatch it.

Comment: how do things like capybera and selinum register mouse events with the browser then?

Comment: Well I realize now that I was phrasing what I was looking for wrong, I have been looking at capybara.  A testing framework that interacts with the browser and rspec/cucumber.  The only issue is now that it doesn't support mousedown only drag and drop

Comment: Sounds good enough to me. You could always test the mousedown part seperately using DOM methods.

Comment: So I found a solution but I had to write it. I am gonna give you the bounty but write about my own answer since yours really helped get me there.

Answer (score 0):

I just successfuly tested code that needed Mouse Events using jasmine and jQuery.

http://api.jquery.com/category/events/event-object/

Just create and trigger events like this:

```
  // Create a new jQuery.Event object with specified event properties.
  var e = jQuery.Event("keydown", { keyCode: 64 });

  // trigger an artificial keydown event with keyCode 64
  jQuery("body").trigger( e );
```

Then use Jasmine to check properties. 
Just as a note, if you need to check animation, you can mock time like this:

//http://groups.google.com/group/jasmine-js/browse_thread/thread/dbdc5ad1c1514322

```
beforeEach(function() { 
  jasmine.Clock.useMock(); 
}); 
//... call the code that calls setTimeout 
jasmine.Clock.tick(500); // advance 500 msec
```

Answer (score -1):

Go and see jQuery and Dojo. Or you can go to jsfiddle site and take a look. They have a set of libraries and you can test online without downloading libraries.